# Exceção do tipo System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Logo após o login no sistema eu tento acessar um página e o sistema me envia novamente para a página de login e logo depois do login novamente realizado acontece esta exceção: "An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in MeuProjeto.dll but was not handled in user code".

Segue a linha onde o erro ocorre:

```
int cod_centro_custo = (int)Session["cod_centrodecusto_usuario"];
```

Fazendo algumas pesquisas aparentemente o código está perdendo as minhas variaveis armazenadas na Session sem motivo algum.

O projeto que eu estou trabalhando é um WebForms com vários projetos. Alguns destes projetos são utilizados para conseguir a informação de um banco de dados SQL Server enquanto outros apenas servem como objetos nos quais eu armazeno informações que foram obtidas com as consultas.
Na página Default.aspx eu faço este código para validar o login e atribuir valores para algumas Sessions:

```
            String login = login_username.Value;
        String senha = login_pass.Value;

        usuario_valeTO cls_usuario = usuario_valeBLL.Getusuario_valeByLoginAndSenha(login, senha);


        if (cls_usuario.cod_usuario >= 1)
        {
            DetalhesTO detalhes = DetalhesBLL.GetDetalhesByCliente(cls_usuario.cod_cliente_usuario);

            Session.Add("detalhes", detalhes);
            Session.Add("cod_centrodecusto_usuario", cls_usuario.cod_centrodecusto_usuario);
            Session.Add("cod_cliente_usuario", cls_usuario.cod_cliente_usuario);
            Session.Add("cod_usuario", cls_usuario.cod_usuario);
            Session.Add("nivel", cls_usuario.nivel);
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, login_username.Value, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2880), RememberMeSet.Checked, cls_usuario.cod_cliente_usuario.ToString() + "//" + cls_usuario.cod_centrodecusto_usuario.ToString(), FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
            string hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hash);

            if (ticket.IsPersistent)
            { cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration; }
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(login_username.Value, RememberMeSet.Checked));
        }
        else
        {
            div_erro.Visible = true;
        }
```

Fazendo o debug eu vejo as Sessions serem preenchidas, mas depois tudo se perde. Alguma ideia do motivo da perda da Session?

[EDIT]

Bom, eu consegui resolver o problema, provavelmente vocês não entenderam o motivo do que eu fiz ter resolvido o problema, mas resolveu...

O problema aparentemente estava no fato de que eu havia setado o meu worspace em um local de rede, uma destas áreas em um servidor que você mapeia e pode utilizar como um disco de armazenamento. Eu me lembrei de que havia trabalhado em um projeto que não conseguia rodar o projeto localmente se os arquivos dele estivessem numa destas áreas de rede, sendo assim eu resolvi remover todos os arquivos do meu projeto desta área e coloquei eles na minha pasta desktop e o problema foi resolvido.

Caso alguém possa dar uma explicação para o motivo desta mudança ter feito a execução local do projeto funcionar seria interessante colocar aqui o motivo. Sendo assim, agradeço a aqueles que tentaram ajudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode testar se a "*session*" não está nula antes de passar o valor.
Exemplo:

```
int cod_centro_custo = 0
if (Session["cod_centrodecusto_usuario"] != null)
   cod_centro_custo = (int)Session["cod_centrodecusto_usuario"];
```

Isso vai evitar o erro de `NullReferenceException` mas não sei porque o sistema fica em loop.

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer desta forma também:

```
int cod_centro_custo = Session["cod_centrodecusto_usuario"] != null ?(int)Session["cod_centrodecusto_usuario"]:0;
```